# Save file as .ps1 in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am currently writing an application to parse out the PowerShell commands from a text file, and then trying to save the results as a .ps1 to run the commands. I have no problem saving the commands as a text file, but I can't seem to figure out how to save the output as a .ps1 file.

Code:

```
        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
        int start = -1;
        int end = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (allLines[i].Equals("STRING powershell Start-Process notepad -Verb runAs") && start == -1)
            {
                start = i;
            }
            else if (allLines[i].Equals("CTRL s") && end == -1)
            {
                end = i;
            }
        }
        string[] lines = allLines[start..end];
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("STRING"))
            {
                output.Add(line.Replace("STRING ", ""));
            }
        }

        File.WriteAllLinesAsync("testOut.ps1", output);
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

When running this code with the line "File.WriteAllLinesAsync("testOut.txt", output)" there are no issues, so the issue seems to be that File.WriteAllLinesAsync() is only able to write to a text file, or at least not able to write to a .ps1 file.

Is there a way of writing to a .ps1 directly, or is there some way to write to the .txt and then convert that .txt to a .ps1?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: An `async` method needs to be `await`ed. If you're not in an `async` method yourself, just use the sync version (`File.WriteAllLines`).

Comment: I still get the same issue when using the WriteAllLines as I do from WriteAllLinesAsync

Comment: A `.ps1` file is nothing more than a text file with a different extension. What, specifically, is the problem you have when you `File.WriteAllLinesAsync("testOut.ps1", output);`?

Comment: You don't need to post your whole project to ask this question. Just try `File.WriteAllLines("C:\\some.stuff", new string[]{"somestuff"})` to see it's working just fine.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I am not getting any error messages or anything, it just seems as if the File.WriteAll is not getting run, or if it is being run, nothing is being done, like no file creation at all.

Comment: If File.WriteAllLines doesn't give you any error messages, it is most likely that you looking for a file in the wrong directory. Try to specify absolute path.